# Laravel ORM should return Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to return an value for an hasOne relation directly with an Model?

For example:

```
$List = Element::orderBy('title')->get();
```

The Element has a "hasOne" Relation to an column:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Type', 'id', 'type_id');
}
```

How can i now return automatically the "type" for the Model?

At the Moment i am looping through all Elements, and build my own "Array" of Objects, including the Key of "type" in this example. But ill prefer to do this only in my Model.

Ill know how to add a "normal" property, but can it be someone from an relation?

```
public function getTypeAttribute($value)
{
    return // how ?
}

protected $appends = array('type');
```

Is this possible?

Edit:

A workaround could be to use DB:: to return the correct value - but ill dont thing thats a good workaround: like:

```
public function getTypeAttribute($value)
{
    // make a query with $this->type_id and return the value of the type_name 
}

protected $appends = array('type');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to eager load your relations when getting the Element:

```
$list = Element::with('type')->orderBy('title')->get();
```

then access the `type` using

```
foreach ($list as $item) {
    echo $item->type->type_name; 
}
```

where `type_name` would be the name of a column in the `types` table

Comment: Hello - thanks for your answer. But ill know that - if ill use with $appends ill get already the "type" - but, and that is the tricky part :) - how can ill get the (in your case, "type_name") without using a foreach loop? can ill add this directly into my model, so if ill check dd($list); my type_name is already a property?

Comment: i forgot to mention you should drop the $appends array, it might overwrite the property. you don't have to loop all the elements to get their relation if you eager load the relation like in the code above. that is somewhat similar to what you're trying to implement in the `getTypeAttribute` function and is already built in Eloquent. [see here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: Thank - now ill understand that. Another question: Is it possible to serialize an Object including Relations for Json without using an foreach loop?

Comment: Using the same syntax and then doing `json_encode($item->toArray());` would yield a json object with all the item relations

Comment: Fine! Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Make a query scope and in that scope, join your attributes from other tables.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Comment: I know how to use joins - but ill want to use the ORM-way to solve that things. I am able to get the "type" property, but ONLY if ill loop though all items and append this. I would like to use "getXXXAttribute" with the correct value.